# App request sent, count increases; Actual request never shown

Tags: facebook, request

Ok .. I am using the Dialog JS API to send requests to people.  I know this is working because

1. The JavaScript callback shows the request ID
2. On the recipient's account, the "App Requests" item on the left side bar has a count which is increasing with each and every request that gets sent

What I cannot figure out is why, although the requests are being sent and the counts are increasing, there is nothing that indicates that a request has in fact been sent.

I have checked the Notifications section and it is empty.  I have also checked the following two URLs, both showing nothing:

- http://www.facebook.com/reqs.php
- http://www.facebook.com/reqs.php#!/?sk=apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging and looking at other peoples apps, I started digging into Facebook's bug tracker and found someone else with the same problem today  Apparently there are a number of "request" bugs today.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/237217296327314

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a valid canvas url and valid secure canvas url in your facebook app settings? May be something to check as I believe it is required.